# vimeo timecode inaccurate using AS3 API

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I am using Vimeo's Flash API so that I can embed and read the timecode of a video using the playProgressHandler, pause it at certain times, pop a menu, and use buttons that trigger seekTo calls. Although everything works, the timecode is inaccurate to varying degrees. Anywhere from 1-2 seconds. I can tell this because:

1) If I play my video on Vimeo and pause it at 6:03 and do the same with it embedded in Flash the visuals do not match up. Flash is lagging behind a tad.

2) I did a test using the JavaScript API. My seekTo calls were consistently accurate. To seek to the same spot using the AS3 API I had to add 1.5 seconds. But even this isn't foolproof. Sometimes it works, but sometimes it's still off.

Any ideas what would account for this inaccuracy and how I might fix this problem? Yes, I can ditch the AS3 and use the JS version, but I'd prefer to just fix what I've already built.

(I also posted this on Vimeo's forum, but I'm following their "Limited support in API Forum" post which suggests to post here)

Comment: Are you able to share any code? Preferably a quick piece of sample code that someone can execute.

Comment: I wasn't sure about sharing my client's code, so I tried to make a simple example for you using Vimeo's ExampleProject.as file (which is what I started with for this project) and adding a button to seek to a certain point. I created a JS version to test against it. Unfortunately, I can't duplicate the timecode issue, perhaps because their sample video is about 30 seconds long and mine is over 30 minutes long. I did try this http://elwinlee.com/blog/2012/02/how-to-fix-flash-seek-playheadtime-accuracy/  but didn't have any luck. So I guess at this point I'm just looking for theories.

Comment: This could probably be an issue with keyframes. instead of jumping to specific spots in time, you probably jump to the nearest keyframe of your desired time (say you want to jump to 6.5s but the nearest keyframe is one 7.1s). I cannot provide any more info than that, but it can't hurt to keep this in mind.

Comment: Interestingly enough, if I seekTo(0) before seeking to another timecode it seems to clear out the inaccuracy. Whether that inaccuracy is a cumulative thing that happens over the course of the movie playing or some sort of buffering glitch I do not know. Unfortunately, if seek too many times the seekTo mechanism breaks entirely. Oh well. I guess this dated and unmaintained API has reached the end of its lifespan.

Comment: Vimeo's Flash API is for their player.  For their player, you use http://developer.vimeo.com/player/as-api

Comment: I am using that API (though I can see how the link I had posted might suggest otherwise... it just happened to point out timecode inaccuracy in Flash so I thought it was relevant even though I'm not using the FLVPlayback component). My guess is that there is simply a +/- 2 second degree of inaccuracy with large videos. I wound up using the large video for the first seamless play through, then broke it up into chapters for reviewing. Not as nice as using a single file, but at least it's a reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's not much we can do to fix this other than to recommend that you use our iframe embed.

It has to do with the way that we retrieve files from our CDN. Because Flash doesn't support byterange requests, we pass a parameter that returns part of the file starting at that position. The nature of how that works means it's always going to be imprecise.